# Android - can't seem to enable JavaScript on a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to enable JavaScript in a WebView?

I am currently trying to enable JavaScript by doing this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);              
            return false;
        }
    });        


    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");


    webview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/user/Okudjavavich");    
}
```

But JS seems to not be enabled because the YouTube videos do not play YouTube ads. Would anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: I would use a better test, rather than assuming that what Google serves up from YouTube is the same for `WebView` than it does for other browsers.

Comment: @CommonsWare well, my main problem is that the YouTube adsense apps aren't being displayed. I think it is an issue with JavaScript not being enabled...am I incorrect somehow?

Comment: I have no way of knowing, as I have never tried to view YouTube videos in a `WebView`. My point is that you are making an assumption about the source of your difficulty with inadequate proof. There are quite a few pages on the Internet, many of which contain JavaScript, that will be more readily testable for *specifically* JavaScript not working. For example, you could try loading http://javatester.org/javascript.html and see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok trying that now and will get back to you with results in a few minutes :)

Comment: @CommonsWare ah yes, it says it supports JavaScript 1.7 ....not sure if that is a recent enough version of js.

Comment: That's what desktop Chrome runs on Linux. Firefox on Linux is using JS 1.8.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, once again, I am very impressed with your help. You are really sharp with this stuff! But would you know why the adsense may not be rendering? I tried it on a mobile browser on my Android phone and it didn't show ads either :(

Comment: It's possible that Google just doesn't serve the ads to mobile browsers. You might try messing with the user-agent and see if you can convince it to serve ads that way.

Comment: @CommonsWare That is interesting. How can I do that? By setting the user agent right in my code? Is there an example of how to do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, trying that now. I wonder if AdSense will frown on me tricking the browser :)

Comment: @CommonsWare setting the user agent to chrome worked, but in the process messed up a number of things on the WebView. So I am trying to set user agent to Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare setting the user agent to Android made it stop playing the videos :) ....would you know what might be a good value to set it to?

Comment: Beats me. Again, I have never tried to view YouTube videos in `WebView`. However, your results would certainly suggest that Google serves different HTML to different browsers. You may be better served playing the YouTube videos with their native player and doing some form of native ads.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that before, but as I recall it was kind of complicated. I think it required using https and some other bells and whistles to get the YouTube player working. Would you know a good tutorial for this?  Thank you!

Comment: "Would you know a good tutorial for this?" -- nope, sorry. I don't have much interest in YouTube on Android. In terms of it being "kind of complicated", so is what you're trying. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to enable JavaScript in a WebView?

Yes, via the code that you have:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

In your case, the problem was that your test (playing YouTube videos and looking for ads) was complicated. A simpler test helped determine that JavaScript indeed *was* enabled, but that something else was influencing Google's YouTube page-serving. In this case, it appears to be based on user agent.